# Counting word occurences from an external file and display them using Erlang?

Tags: file, count, erlang

I am having trouble fully understanding how to count how many times an element occurs within a text file.  I am able to read the file in like so -

```
-module(list3).

-export([readlines/1]).

readlines(FileName) ->
{ok, Device} = file:open(FileName, [read]),
try get_all_lines(Device)
  after file:close(Device)
end.

get_all_lines(Device) ->
case io:get_line(Device, "") of
    eof  -> [];
    Line -> Line ++ get_all_lines(Device)
end.
```

I would transfer the text file into a list of strings and I understand that list:length or foldl would normally count the number of elements within a list returning overall how many words there would be, however, I would like to list the words within the file and how many times it has occurred.  Would this be done through pattern matching? The only solution that I can currently think of would require a lot of code.

Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: I may not have worded this correctly so feel free to point out areas I should alter.

Answer (score 0):

You can find example of word counting here: http://www.roberthorvick.com/2009/07/02/word-frequency-redux-erlang-list-comprehension-regex-and-list-folding/